# How to mint Dai to Goerli testnet wallet?

Tags: etherscan, mint, dai, goerli, zksync

Trying to get lots of Dai (need like 300,000+) on Goerli to transfer to zksync alpha testnet.

When I try to just directly mint to my wallet's address on etherscan using the contract web interface, metamask forces me to switch to the mainnet and won't allow me to pay gas fees in anything other than mainnet ETH. I'm not sure why that is or if I'm doing something wrong.

When I select the approve() call from etherscan, though, it doesn't force me to switch networks. Just for mint() and rely().

This method works perfectly fine on rinkeby and I'm able to mint unlimited Dai directly to my wallet through concurrent calls without having to approve() or rely().

Open to alternatives on getting lots of testnet Dai, but a solution for the above is most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy it from uniswap, get some ETH from a faucet like https://faucet.paradigm.xyz/ and use it to swap for DAI using the goerli testnet on uniswap. 
Last time I checked, it took a little less than 0.1 ETH to buy 300,000 DAI on goerli.
And the faucet gives you something like 0.5 ETH each time you use it.

Answer (score 0):

Saw you mentioned Rinkeby. Quick note - it, Ropsten, and Kovan are now all deprecated. The only ethereum testnet now is Goerli. If you need Goerli testETH, you can use Alchemy's free faucet to get testETH daily - https://goerlifaucet.com/.

You probably will need to swap Goerli testETH to mint Dai as @RubenSantana mentioned prior.

Answer (score 0):

I just did [it](https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x407a1d252723e804e86a78ef8d5ac0838927bc8d83c94710769447d11a2a1ccc) with the MINT function. It is working as per normal.

I am using Metamask too.

Do you have any GETH?